# Issues regarding my take on proving $E(X) = \lambda$, where $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, expectation, poisson-distribution

My proof:
Let $X\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$.
Then $$f_{\Tiny{X}}(x) = \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} e^{-\lambda}.$$
Thus, $E(X) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x f_{\Tiny{X}}(x) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} e^{-\lambda} = \lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!} = \lambda e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda}=\lambda$.
$\hspace{16cm}\blacksquare$

I know that the result of the expected value of $X$ is $\lambda$. However, I don't think that $(x-1)!$ exists (to my knowledge) when $x = 0$.
Then $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}$ doesn't exactly make sence since Poisson random variable $X$ takes value from $\{0, 1, 2,\dots\}$.

I have noticed that some of the posts for proving $E(X)= \lambda$ change the summation from $x=0$ to $x=1$ when they cancel $x$ with $\frac{1}{x!}$.
Can anyone explain to me that why you can just change the initial value for the summation?

Many thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: I think you can overcome that little problem by beginning the sum for the expectation from $\;x=1\;$ ,as otherwise the first summand is zero anyway.

Comment: $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x f_{\Tiny{X}}(x)=0+\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x f_{\Tiny{X}}(x)$$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Oh, I see. Thank you guys so much. But just another quick question, if $\frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!} = \frac{x}{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$, then, when $x = 0$, how come $\frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}$ doesn't make sense whereas $\frac{x}{\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}=0$?

Comment: Please Note $$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty }{x\frac{{{\lambda }^{x}}}{x!}{{e}^{-\lambda }}=0+}\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty }{x\frac{{{\lambda }^{x}}}{x!}{{e}^{-\lambda }}=\lambda }{{e}^{-\lambda }}\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\lambda }^{x-1}}}{(x-1)!}}=\lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\lambda }^{x}}}{x!}}$$

Comment: @behrouzMaleki, Ok, I see. my mistake